# Temperature input file for Abaqus

Tags: python, abaqus

I m very new with Python scripting and fortran. I am currently doing research on thermal profiling for laser melting. I developed a formula for time-dependent temperature profile that matches experimental results but don't know how to write an input file so abaqus can use this formula for calculating the temperature for each time increment.
Anyone with ideas on this will be really appreciated. Tnx

Comment: Can you explain what parameters your formular takes (coordinates, time, ...)?

Comment: (x,y,z,t) where t is the incremental time

Comment: If your formular is not super simple like T=f(x,y,z)+k*t. I would suggest to use subroutine like `UMATHT`. The exact subroutine depends on your type of analysis

Comment: The formula is quite simple and straightforward obtained from interpolating experimental data and of the form T(x,y,z)=sqrt(3.456+ exp(0.245t) ; not exactly this but of the same format

Comment: Still need suggestions from others about this. How do I use Umatht to define a time dependent temperature profile

Comment: Though not entire sure, maybe you can define two fields, one changing linear with time and the other as a function of the first one. Maybe you can achieve this by setting a simple constrain equation. Writing UMATHT may be overkill for your task

Comment: Can u pls give an simple example of how the fortran or Python program should look like. Just a base that I can build upon cos I'm a novice on this

Comment: You still need to decide if you want the solution for the solver (Fortran) or for post-processing (Python). During post-processing you can create reports, additional field outputs, ...

Comment: I meant a solution for the fortran solver

Comment: Why don't you write a  UTEMP or UDISP or FILM fortran subroutine that can directly apply the temperature onto your model using a simple formula? The Abaqus subroutines manual will give you examples on how to do this.

Comment: Any chance you can separate the time and spatial components? You can create a field for x,y,z and then an amplitude for time.